# My data from firestore not retrieve using dart flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using cloud fire store in flutter I did:

1. connected the app with the firebase
2. put the google-services.json in app buil.gradle
3. add the dependency and plugin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'کوردی پۆلی یەک',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget{

  List<Widget> makeListWidget(AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document){
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(document["name"]),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("کوردی پۆلی یەک",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('lesson').snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            switch(snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Center(child: Text('No data'));
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                    child:CircularProgressIndicator());
              default:
                return ListView(
                  children:makeListWidget(snapshot),
                );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is just loading and when ever I delete the `connectionState.waiting` gives me error:

> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'documents' was called on null. Receiver: null
>   Tried calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the firestore security rules to the following:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Haddad I have done this it is not working

Comment: Can u print the snapshot? print(snapshot) inside the method `makeListWidget(AsyncSnapshot`

Comment: i just recreate the project but this time i tried it with test mode it is working now with the same code but what will i face in future when i want to change it to real mode? @Peter Haddad

Comment: @Asia I'm not sure, but what you need to do is debug this issue, you can add breakpoints or use print(snapshot) to see what you get

Comment: thanks so much i realized another solution was change the permission allow read, write: if true; to  allow read, write;

Comment: because i just got the answer before 1 hour @Peter Haddad Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

change the allow read, write: if true; to allow read, write;